# Puppet , Hiera | how get value

Tags: linux, yaml, puppet, hiera

I am use puppet + hiera.

hiera.yaml

```
version: 5

defaults:
    data_hash: yaml_data
    datadir: hieradata

hierarchy:
    - name: "Node data"
      path: "nodes/%{trusted.certname}.yaml"
    - name: "OU3 data"
      path: "ou/%{facts.ou_new.0}.yaml"
    - name: "Global data"
      path: "global.yaml"
```

path: "ou/%{facts.ou_new.0}.yaml" - not working

i have array (from puppet facts)

```
{
  "name":"anton-test-1l.adm72.local",
  "values":{
     ......
    "ou_new":{
          "ou0":"Linux",
          "ou1":"my1",
          "ou2":"my2"
        },
    .....
}
```

how get value from "ou2" in "ou_new" array.

i need right simple example.

puppetserver version: 6.13.0
hiera 3.5.0

Comment: Your fact for `ou_new` appears to be a `Hash[String, String]` and not a `Array[String]`, so I do not believe `facts.ou_new.0` will resolve correctly since it access an Array element.

Comment: @MattSchuchard how to refer to the hash?

Comment: What is the name of the fact that hash is coming from? Your `path` should be something more like `${facts.<factname>.values.ou_new.ou2}` if my understanding of what you are asking is correct. Or if that hash is an actual external fact, `path` should be `${facts.values.ou_new.ou2}`